# How i can extract all html tags and there content from a string using php

Tags: php, regex

I have following content in a string

```
<p class="link-pages">
    LQ
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 1</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 2</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 3</span>
    <span class="page-link">Chapter 4</span>
</p>
```

Now using the regex i want to extract all contents and tag. Is there any inbuilt function in php for this.

Comment: [`preg_match_all`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php); what is your regex?

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/215042)!

Comment: @RobIII heh, counterpoint directly below - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/1454048

Comment: @admdrew [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). Regexes are "fine" for very simple "HTML tasks" but as your project grows and this (currently) simple snippet grows to something larger you already took the wrong path. Better start off on the right foot and get it right from the start.

Comment: Sure, I was just pointing out the irony of the blanket (but generally correct) statement "can't" in your linked comment that was immediately followed by another (also correct) comment giving the counterpoint.

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first.

Answer (score 4):

Use PHP's [Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php),  [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), [Ganon](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/), [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) or any of the other available alternatives.

DO **[NOT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/215042)** use regexes for handling HTML.

Best you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/215042) and/or read [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).